# Preserve state with Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have an app with a ng-view that sends emails to contact selected from a contact list.
When the users select "Recipient" it shows another view/page where he can search, filter, etc. "Send email" and "Contact list" are different html partials that are loaded in the ng-view.

I need to keep the send form state so when the users select someone from the Contact List it returns to the same point (and same state). I read about different solutions ($rootScope, hidden divs using ng-show, ...) but I want to know if UI-router will help me with it's State Manager. If not, are there other ready-to-use solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - saving data between routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802857/angularjs-saving-data-between-routes)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution i have gone with is using services as my data/model storage.  they persist across controller changes.

example

the user service ( our model that persists across controller changes )

```
app.factory('userModel', [function () {
    return {
        model: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        }
    };
}]);
```

using it in a controller

```
function userCtrl($scope, userModel) {
    $scope.user = userModel;
}
```

the other advantage of this is that you can reuse your model in other controllers just as easly.

Comment: I neved used services. It looks fine. But what if model is created based on a route parameter (eg: $routeParams.myId)?

Comment: you would store the results in the service rather than the controller.  everything else can be the same

Comment: It appears that your example is incomplete, you need a way to [broadcast](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/) changes in your service model to other controllers. [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16559855/168815) also accounts for saving state when navigating away from the app altogether.

Comment: @JonathonHill the example is specific to the question ( i hope ).  the link to the example you have commented on happens to be mine as well :), and yes it give more context to on how to implement the specifics

Comment: @Anton The very disadvantage I see in your approach because I am just experiencing it... is the fact that you can not inject the $scope into a factory thus you can not have computed properties in your userModel which would change when the user types into a textbox, but your whole userModel is bound to the $scope.user thats a problem a real one.

Comment: If you're only storing some data like name and email, the [Angular FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) recommends not using a service "just to store and return some bits of data". You can use a a [value](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) instead.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if this is recommended or not, but I created a StateService to save/load properties from my controllers' scopes. It looks like this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app').service('StateService', function(){

        var _states = {};

        var _save = function(name, scope, fields){
            if(!_states[name])
                _states[name] = {};
            for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
                _states[name][fields[i]] = scope[fields[i]];
            }
        }
        var _load = function(name, scope, fields){
            if(!_states[name])
                return scope;
            for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
                if(typeof _states[name][fields[i]] !== 'undefined')
                    scope[fields[i]] = _states[name][fields[i]];
            }
            return scope;
        }

        // ===== Return exposed functions ===== //
        return({
            save: _save,
            load: _load
        });

    });
})();
```

To use it, I put some code at the end of my controller like this:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'StateService', function ($scope, StateService) {
    $scope.keyword = '';
    $scope.people = [];

    ...

    var saveStateFields = ['keyword','people'];
    $scope = StateService.load('ExampleCtrl', $scope, saveStateFields);
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        StateService.save('ExampleCtrl', $scope, saveStateFields);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: seems to be a possible solution for me. Have you had proven success with this process? I now need to also implement a mechanism to preserve state. Greets Mario

Comment: I haven't used it in a production app, but my in-development app is using this code and seems to work pretty well.

Comment: Super job Justin! My colleague is happy with the solution! Wish you a nice weekend.

Comment: Perfect solution Justin.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works really nice

Answer (score 2):

I have found [Angular-Multi-View](https://github.com/vincentdieltiens/Angular-Multi-View) to be a godsend for this scenario. It lets you preserve state in one view while other views are handling the route. It also lets multiple views handle the same route.

You can do this with UI-Router but you'll need to nest the views which IMHO can get ugly.