# How to preserve state of hidden views?

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm an Angular newbie working on a Phonegap application with a few views: a map, a list, and search.

As the user interacts, each view accumulates some UI state: the map is dragged, the list gets a scroll position, a detail view is opened for a list item, a search is performed, etc. I'd like for the user to be able to navigate among views without losing this state.

When I put my views in partials in ng-view, and my nav links use `href="#/path"`, or ng-click to trigger `location.path(path)`, the controller is run and state is obliterated. Makes sense.

One option would be to ng-include all partials in index.html and ng-show based on the user's nav actions. However, I've found that this kind of complexity in the DOM will lead to poor Phonegap performance. It also feels that by eschewing routing, I'm losing one of the main benefits of using Angular.

Another thought: nav clicks cause traversal of browser history. Seems tricky to maintain the state of all views in parallel, however.

My question: is there a good pattern for this?

FWIW currently using Phonegap 3.0 and Angular 1.1.5. Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: how to revert back to the runtime loaded DOM elements in the previous view on going back (preserve state)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172207/angularjs-how-to-revert-back-to-the-runtime-loaded-dom-elements-in-the-previous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the state of the DOM in parallel views, there's an extension to ui-router called [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky). It has a a nice demo with state transitions and full DOM preservation when switching among tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can keep all the data that needs to persist between controller reloads in services

a simple example here

[Preserve state with Angular UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023823/preserve-state-with-angular-ui-router/18027844#18027844)

a more complex example here that includes restoring state if the user leaves the page and then presses the back button

[Maintain model of scope when changing between views in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940974/maintain-model-of-scope-when-changing-between-views-in-angularjs/16559855#16559855)