# Angularjs: how to revert back to the runtime loaded DOM elements in the previous view on going back (preserve state)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, savestate

I have an angular application which has two views:

**1) List view**

**2) Detail View**

when you click on the thumbnail from list view you go to detail view, here is the route:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl',

      }).
      when('/list/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
        controller: 'DetailCtrl',

      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
      });
  }]);
```

Now there is a function loadmore in 'listCtrl' controller which is used to load

```
myControllers.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Troll', '$http',

function ($scope, $location, Troll, $http) {
    $scope.Trolls = Troll.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'popular';
    $scope.fromData = {};
    //console.log($scope.Trolls);
    //this will be used to fetch the data in json which is defined in services.js

    $scope.loadmore = function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'trolls/trolls.php?troll_index=' + $('#main-content #item-list .sub-item').size(),
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {


                if (response != null) {
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {

                        $scope.Trolls.push({
                            UID: response[index].UID,
                            id: response[index].id,
                            popular: response[index].popular,
                            imageUrl: response[index].imageUrl,
                            name: response[index].name,
                            tags: response[index].tags,
                            category: response[index].category
                        });

                    });
                }
            },
            complete: function () {},
            error: function () {
                console.log('Failed!');
            }
        });
        $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';
        $http.get('trolls/trolls.php?troll_id=' + Troll);

    }

}]);
```

**PROBLEM**:
now the problem is,
After clicking on loadmore if i go to detail view and i come back on list view my newly loaded divs are gone how do i preserve them??

Comment: have you tried Angular's $templateCache? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

Comment: i read $templateCache but how is it relevant to my question here can you explain me with some demo??

Comment: Any reason you're using `jQuery.ajax` instead of `$http`?

Comment: "newly loaded divs are gone". Do they then come back, after the ajax request has run again?

Comment: Ajax request only appends the DOM elements so they dont get deleted until you move to the next view.

Comment: To add to @MichalCharemza comment; why are you using jQuery at all?  You already have Angular!

Comment: i have removed $.ajax() now i am using:$http.get('trolls/trolls.php?troll_index='+$('#item-list .sub-item').length).success(function(response){ //my code }); but still i cant achieve what i want.

Comment: @Alex what problems are you still having?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you change routes the controller that is in charge of that route is initialized when the route is loaded and destroyed when the route is changed. So the reason you lose your data is the controller is reinitialized and the previous data never exists.

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Higher level controller that is not destroyed - could potentially live on the body - this passes its scope to the children controllers. But this is not a true modularization of concerns. For this issue... Can be very useful for other issues - Authentication, Profile, etc.
2. The way I would advocate is to pull this into a service for example - listService - this will fetch and cache the data and pass it back to the listController when its reloaded, thus preventing the data from being lost.

---

**First way to solve could be this...**

So if you have a higher level controller in charge of fetching the data or move it into a service which is what I would do, then the data that is loaded from loadMore function will continue to be there, but it needs to be on a higher parent scope that is not destroyed on the route change.

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="ApplicationController">
     <!-- Code Here -->
</body>
```

Controller:

```
myControllers.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
     var data = [];

     $scope.loadmore = function () {
        // Use Angular here!!! $http not jQuery! 
        // Its possible to write a complete Angular app and not ever true jQuery
        // jQuery Lite the Angular implementation will be used though
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'trolls/trolls.php?troll_index=' + $('#main-content #item-list .sub-item').size(),
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {


                if (response != null) {
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {

                        data.push({
                            UID: response[index].UID,
                            id: response[index].id,
                            popular: response[index].popular,
                            imageUrl: response[index].imageUrl,
                            name: response[index].name,
                            tags: response[index].tags,
                            category: response[index].category
                        });

                    });
                }

                return data;

            }
            error: function () {
                console.log('Failed!');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

However I dont really like this approach as its a bit hacky...and jQuery is used...

**Second approach using a service to fetch/cache:**

So lets pull it into a service instead.

```
myServices.factory('listService', function($http, $q) {

   var//iable declaration 
      service = {},
      list = []
   ;
   /////////////////////   
   //Private functions//
   /////////////////////

   function loadMore(url) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http({ method: 'GET', url: url }) // Need to pass in the specific URL maybe from the DOM scoped function?
      .success(function(data) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function() {
        deferred.reject();
        //Do error things
      });   

     return deferred.promise; 
   }

   ////////////////////
   //Public Functions//
   ////////////////////

   service.loadMore = function(url) { 
      // Used for loading more data
      loadMore(url).then(function(data) {
        list.push(data);
        return list
      });
   }

   service.getList = function() {
      // Returns the currently loaded data
      return list;
   }

 return service;

});
```

Then in your controller:

```
myControllers.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Troll', listService

function ($scope, $location, Troll, listService) {
    $scope.Trolls = Troll.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'popular';
    $scope.fromData = {};


    $scope.loadmore = function(subItemSize) { //add url specific params here
       var url = 'trolls/trolls.php?troll_index=' + subItemSize;
       return listService.loadMore(url);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: getting this error while implementing the services method:  [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: listServiceProvider <- listService

Comment: you need to add it as a module dependancy sample place you add the myController place

Comment: I upvoted this but wanted to point out that option 2 is probably the best way to go.

Comment: @BrianGlick I agree, also stated in the post.

Comment: How can DOM elements be preserved, e.g. a Google map that should keep its zoom/pan state when the user returns to that route? CC @BrianGlick.

Comment: @DanDascalescu keep track of that stuff in a service!

Comment: @StenMuchow: how? I'll have `$service.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),  mapOptions);` and the `<div id="map">` will still get destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

use ui-router instead:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router, you can have multiple ui-view and also you can use relative routes, you should define child states, this way the parent state remains unchanged when route changes to a child state, check out this video:https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router

i created a plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/FA3DuHgngKD2CIPG5bHW?p=preview

Comment: @StenMuchow If your list view is a ui.router parent state, and the detail view is a child state, then going into the detail view (and back) wouldn't destroy or re-initialize the list.

Comment: @MichalCharemza I agree, but when I commented on this post it didn't contain the updated info.

Comment: Sorry guys but i have tried all the methods that you have mentioned but none seems to work for me.

Comment: @Alex - What problems are you getting? Still the injector error?

Comment: I would use this approach.  UI-Router is really freaking good for state based views.

Comment: i tried using UI router in the initial time only but it gives me an error UI router not found i am following the tutorial given on the angular site if you can provide me with a demo with all the files that'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can store data in a service or cache it into the Angular cache, but your divs will still be gone when you route back to that view.

If you want to **preserve the state of the DOM too**, there's an extension to `ui-router` called [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky). It has a a nice demo with state transitions and full DOM preservation when switching among tabs.

[image]