# UI-Router: How to preserve views while switching views

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a webapp with `angular` 1.x and `ui-router` 0.3.x. When I switch to a new view state, corresponding controller will be instantiated (data state will be reset). As you can see from the following code snippet, terminal (actually this is jquery.terminal) will be created every time when I switch to `/logview` and will be destroyed when the view state is changed to something else.

```js
angular.module('app')
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('logview', {
      url: '/logview',
      templateUrl: 'views/logview/logview.html',
      controller: 'LogViewCtrl'
    });
  }])
  .controller('LogViewCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     var terminal = $('#terminal').terminal();
     console.log(terminal created');
     $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      terminal.destroy();
    });
  }])
;
```

I want to preserve the `logview` and leave it running in background, so that when I switch back to `logview` again, I can see all log messages since the webapp starts..

*Update 1: I searched around SO, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837851/angular-ui-router-how-to-preserve-views-while-switching-views) has an answer quite fit the requirement, which is using `ng-show` to show/hide a log view. This gonna be a way to go. However I need to design the layout very carefully because I use `kendo-splitter`. It will use absolute container width and height. A hidden div will mess the calculation up.*

Comment: Controllers are always created and destroyed. Use a service to save state

Comment: I checked `ui-router`'s `controllerProvider`, it can dynamic instantiate a controller but it cannot cache any controller instance. I'm going to redesign the layout and then use `ng-show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling around, including checking [some discussion](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/63) from ui-router's community, I finally found an excellent ui-router plugin called [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky), which provides a magical flag `sticky=true`, so that I have persist `ui-view` now.

Answer (score 2):

In ui-route, the basic principle of state and controller is to load and to destroy again and again. You can use Phil's suggestion (use service). I've faced a similar problem once. I came up with a trick. When the controller loads, just define a $rootscope object. Then every time when the controller loads check if the object exists/defined. If defined don't execute your code. Else define the $rootscope object and execute code.

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMessages'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$rootscope) {
if (!$rootscope.myCtrl){
        $rootscope.myCtrl = 'exist';
        // Code you don't want to execute in this controller again and again goes here.

        var terminal = $('#terminal').terminal();
        console.log(terminal created');
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            terminal.destroy();
        };
    // Code you want to execute in this controller goes here.
});
```

I think this'll serve your purpose.

Comment: Actually the view is destroyed by ui-router, when the state is changed. So even if I avoid reinitialize a controller as you suggested, I cannot bind the existing controller with new view, which is the same but was destroyed and recreated by ui-router.

Comment: You can put condition in your view with the $rootscope variable that I suggested earlier.
A plunker would be useful. Can you provide one?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to keep `views` or `state` using `Ui.Router` is **implementing nested routes**: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views

Comment: Thanks for hinting me this leads. I know ui-router supports nested states native. But my problem is not about a nested structure. I have multiple states, they are flat. But one state (`/logview`) wants to be persist. When I click "Logview" tab on navbar the first time, ui-router will render view as new state. When I switch to another tab, the "Logview" will still active in background, but other tab will always render as new state.

Comment: You need to wrap your entire application inside a `Root State`, maybe abstract, that holds each information you want to persist.