# AngularJS ui-router keep state loaded in background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am designing an AngularJS project in which one of the states loads a view with a flash object. How would I keep the flash object loaded in the background in between state changes so that the object doesn't have to reload when returning to the state with the flash object.

Comment: Please add code or create a plunkr of what you have tried right now.

Comment: you can use session storage https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet as I have no idea how to do it. I just have my states setup with ui.router and when you navigate to a different page the current page is deleted from the dom to make room for the next state. I just need the dom to stay hidden in the background until you navigate back to the state with the flash object.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172207/angularjs-how-to-revert-back-to-the-runtime-loaded-dom-elements-in-the-previous

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out an answer. In my case I was trying to keep a flash object hidden in the background but wanted it to also remain loaded. I found out about "sticky states" which I used to allow the ui view containing the object to remain in the DOM. I kept trying to use "display: hidden;" on the object but that would cause the object to reload when it came back into display. Found that using simple CSS tricks and the "visibility: hidden" style did the trick!

Comment: more info: [ui-router-extras](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky)