# communicating between two separate Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

what is the best way to have two directives talk to each other? Lets say I have the following setup:

```
<drop-uploader></drop-uploader>
<drop-uploader></drop-uploader>

<progress-bar></progress-bar>
```

whats the best way to have the "uploader" directive notify the "progress bar" directive? Is the best way to use events on the rootScope or use a service? Is there a way to reference a directive as an attribute on another directive to access its scope? Something like this...

```
<drop-uploader progress-bar="thisone"></drop-uploader>
<drop-uploader progress-bar="thisone"></drop-uploader>

<progress-bar name="thisone"></progress-bar>
```

Comment: This might help [Egghead.io - AngularJS - Directive to Directive Communication](http://youtu.be/rzMrBIVuxgM)

Comment: I saw that video but he is demonstrating how to communicate between two directives on the same dom element. Great video though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options for sharing data between controllers (check for "require" in the docs) but as far as I have understood it you can't use that method to share data between siblings. It has to be parent/child (someone correct me if I am wrong).

You can however share data using services. There is only one instance of each service no matter how many different controllers/services/directives invoke it, so setting the data in one will update the other.

The sollution outlined here will work for directives as well as controllers: [Angularjs, passing scope between routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882077/angularjs-passing-scope-between-routes)

Comment: Btw, if you are just signaling, not actually sharing data two ways, I think a broadcast might better like Chandermani mentioned.

Comment: so I figured out a way to do my proposed setup using angular.element to select the element and calling scope() on that element to get its scope. just not sure of the pros/cons of doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for events using $rootScope `$broadcast` as all other mechanism introduce a state into the system which you need to keep in sync.

Be it using a property on the `rootscope` or creating a service which has a shared variable.

Also if the scenario fits into a eventing pattern then `$broadcast` would be better.