# Angularjs, setting the value of a value service at runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to Angularjs. I am working on my personal website and am using angular. I want people to be able to login. After logging in I want to store there username in a valueservice so that it is available all the time. Can I do it.

I tried doing it in config() function but was not successful. The reason i am using config function is because here i am checking if the user was already logged in.

Thanks.

Comment: How does your login function? Is it a cookie set back-end that you then want to use to read the user data via a service and expose it to the rest of the app? Is the core problem here that you can't get it to read the user or that you can't share it properly to the rest of the app?

Comment: i am using firebase api. I know they have an integration but am trying to make my own firebase services

Comment: the core issue is i want to maintain some global variables that can be set at runtime and may change. login email id is just one of them

Comment: In that case you use either the rootScope or a service. I've added an answer with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways of storing data that is supposed to be globally available in Angular.

The first is to store it on the $rootScope. The rootScope is the root of all other scopes (as the name implies), so it is always available in all templates and it can be injected into any controller/service/etc. It is used just like the normal $scope, so a login service would do something like:

```
app.service('LoginService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var user = {}; //Get the user somehow
    $rootScope.user = user;
}
```

The second way is to use a service share persisted data. See [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882077/angularjs-passing-scope-between-routes) for more info about that.

---

In this case I would say go with the first, use $rootScope. When you have something that should be globally available the rootScope fits perfectly, if you have something that should be shared between only a few parts of the app, use a service.

A good place to call your login service is in the app.run() method. It is run first thing when the app starts (except after config I believe).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set service value in module config function, but you can do it in module run blocks
From angular official docs:

> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. ***Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks.*** This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. ***Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks.*** This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.

Related link: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module