# Angularjs route with hidden parameters like a http post

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Can I get hidden parameters like a http post with $location?

Concept of what I'm thinking:

```
$location.param(key, value);
$location.path('/myPLace');
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: You can just `$location.path('/myPlace?' + key + '=' + value)`

Comment: Thanks mombabur, but that solution redirects to my .otherwise clause instead of 'myPlace'...

Comment: @Narek, how is it not clear with the title and the example? Very frivolous with the down voting :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you like to share values/parameter between different routes?

The example from @mobabur94 works, but the parameter is not hidden.

To hold parameters between routes, you could use a service. Take a look at this:

[Angularjs, passing scope between routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882077/angularjs-passing-scope-between-routes)