# Angularjs - set view object from $rootscope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angularjs webapp contains Login view and Home view.

After logging in, I want my credentials to be saved in order to use them in the future.

For this I saved them in my $rootScope.

Now in my homeController I set them to my $scope this way:

```
$scope.user = $rootScope.user;
$scope.password = $rootScope.password;
```

and in my HomeController, the value is properly passed.

When I try to set the value of $scope.user to my DOM using {{using}}, it doesnt seem to work.

Here is the HomeController

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Home')

.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',

    function ($scope, $rootScope) {    
        $scope.user = $rootScope.username;
    }]);
```

and here is my home view:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController as HomeCtrl">
    <h1></h1>
    <p>{{user}}</p>

    <p><a href="#/login">Logout</a></p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry for the nooby question and feel free to add more info on how to manage such scenario.

Comment: You don't need to `$scope.user = $rootScope.user`. Since `$scope` is a child of `$rootScope`, by inheritance the `user` variable is automatically available in all your `$scope`s.

Comment: I suggest saving the login data in a service component instead of the scope. So you can inject them everywhere you need them. Look here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882077/angularjs-passing-scope-between-routes

Comment: There is no need to copy the values from $rootScope to local $scope, you can just use them in your html sinde $scope's inherit from parent $scope.

Comment: I disagree. It's better to call $rootScope, because nothing guarantees you that there will never be another variable named "user" for example, between your scope and the $rootScope.

Comment: Also, {{ }} does not set a value to the DOM, it tells angular, to evaluate the expression inside {{ }}, in the current scope, and replace {{ }} with the result (thus it does much more than place a value). Don't mind it too much, just trying to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `<p>{{HomeCtrl.user}}</p>`.

You are using an alias for your controller, and as shown [in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), you need to include that alias to reference its scope.

Edit: Since this was accepted, I'll link the [related plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tZZBNKKgYuvvjShJZcYE) from the chat.

Comment: True that, @eeadev why are you using an alias for your controller?

Comment: It's not a "bad" idea per se, it's not necessary here though (and it may confuse you).

Comment: @JeremyThille, actually for no reason at the moment

Comment: @K.Gkinis, thanks but it still does not change my view

Comment: Can you give me a plunker/fiddler whatever?

Comment: Also, do you have any tool to inspect angular scopes?  Like batarang (for chrome)?

Comment: thanks @K.Gkinis; no, I dont use batarang. Here is a fiddler with app.js: https://jsfiddle.net/9nokLbhz/1/ and the other relevant files are wrote in this post. Is it possible to add more windows to fiddler?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100170/discussion-between-eeadev-and-k-gkinis).